# Background agent process goes into idle state in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing GPS based Windows Phone 7 Application. In which I have used Background Agent (Periodic Task) for performing certain task on regular basis in background process.

I am facing one problem here, our Application Background Agent goes into idle mode after 30 minutes and doesn’t perform any task. My Application demands that Background Agent should Run continuously. Here I can’t use Resource Intensive Task because my Application requirement won’t fulfill Resource Intensive task criteria.

How can I disable Battery Saver mode? So that It can run continuously.

Please give me some guideline here.

I am waiting for valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Each background task runs only once in cca 30 minutes. There is no way in Windows Phone 7 to run code continuosly in the background